# Interpolation on shell script bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a data file containing values of longitudes and latitudes (displayed on two columns) measured by a GPS along a profile at regular intervals. at a certain point on my profile, the GPS stopped working, hence in my data i have zeros instead of values of longitudes and latitudes. I want to interpolate between this fields to get values of longitudes and latitudes instead of zeros.

to be more clear here is a simple example of how my file looks like.

```
[12  7] ;
[14  8 ];
[0   0];
[0   0];
[20  11];
[22  12]
```

NB: the number are on two columns, it's the editor's problem

i want to interpolate where i got zeros. i am working on bash and i have no idea on how to do it

Comment: sorry for data display, normally they are on two columns. i just want to linear interpolate between the values bounding the zero values

Comment: What output do you expect in the given case?

Comment: i espect [16 9] for the first zero line and [18 10] for the second zero line

Comment: Hm, well, what if the last but one line was `[19 12]` instead?

Comment: infact i want a linear interpolation which will give values between the second and last but one line.

Comment: Are you aware that bash doesn't handle float point arithmetics?

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck with a linear regression done once for the first column and once for the second column.

Assume we're working on the first column. The input / x axis is the index of the measurement, and the output / y axis is the measurement itself. So your data can become ((1, 12), (2, 14), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 20), (6, 22)). Based on the known input-output relationships, for indices (1, 2, 5, 6), you need to deduce a formula of the form y = ax + b. So you basically need to find a and b. Once you have those you can find the y for input 3 as 3a + b and the y for input 4 as 4a + b.

You'll find a different a and b for the second column.

How to find a and b is a little bit complicated. You can look at [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/252) article for a nice introduction as well as the formulas for computing a and b (named b0 and b1 inside).

One last thing - I would not attempt doing such a thing in Bash. While it is possible, as Bash has support for arrays and math, it is not what it was designed for. Call out to Matlab/Octave or R, and use their results. Those tools have builtin support for reading files such as yours as well as for doing the regression.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with awk, here is a script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN   { FS="[ [\\];]+"
        # decide on the number of floating digits for the interpolated figures
        FMTStr= "[%.1f, %.1f];\n"
        }

        { if( ($2== 0) && ( $3 == 0) ) { zeroLines++ }
          else {
            for( i = 1; i <= zeroLines; i++ ) {
                t1 = prev1 + (($2 - prev1) / (zeroLines + 1 )) * i
                t2 = prev2 + (($3 - prev2) / (zeroLines + 1 ) ) * i
                printf(FMTStr, t1, t2)
            }
            # either printf(FMTStr, $2, $3) #or
            print $0
            prev1 = $2
            prev2 = $3
            zeroLines = 0
          }
        }
```

Use it so: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`, it gives you

```
[12  7] ;
[14  8 ];
[16.0, 9.0];
[18.0, 10.0];
[20  11];
[22  12];
```

Comment: thanks, the scripts works but only problem is that it does an interpolation for all the lines while i want an interpolation only where i have lines with zeros

Comment: @lefloxy I changed the script a bit and added example output

Comment: please can you explain me the first line on the field separator FS? infact my data has no brackets, it's simply two columns of numbers separated by spaces (two spaces before the first column and in between them.

Comment: @lefloxy The input example in the question has e.g. first line `[12  7] ;`. The `FS` statement deals with getting the numbers out  of it: which means ignore the `[`,`]`, ` ` and `;` I implemented the "ignoring" by defining that symbols as field separators. Please update the question with example data that you really have, then I can change the script accordingly.   

At the moment I assume that you need to change: every `$2` into `$1` and every `$3` into `$2`.

Comment: thanks i understand more, my data is of the form 12  7 with two spaces before the 12 and two spaces between the 12 and 7. i just defined the field seperator by default and it worked. thanks alot :)

Comment: sorry i have 1 more question. if i have different number of spaces say 2 spaces before 12 and 5 spaces between 12 and 7, how do i define my FS to maintain this spaces in the output

Comment: Due to the `+` it should not make a difference when defining `FS="[ ]+"` or using the `FS` statement from the answer.